# Multiple page Phonegap App without JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I have created a few mobile app using phonegap and i have used jquery mobile, purely because the controls are nice looking, but mainly because it has the nice changePage function.  I like to have multiple html documents to break up the code, and with over 10 separate screens i think it keeps the code tidier.

Can anyone tell me, how to normally changePage with a nice "slide" animation without using JQuery mobile, using multiple html pages.  Is this possible?

I will still be using JQuery, but i would like to use something like chocolateUI or twitter bootstrap for the design of the controls.

Any examples would be much appreicated, i have tried googling this but all the results say "how to change page with JQuery Mobile" and i do not want this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want it to function like a single-page layout but you want to store the content in different files?

Comment: Yes i want the slide animation of moving from 1 page to another.  i dont what to have too many things in the dom at one time as this could slow performance (i believe) so would like page code in separate html files

Comment: Have you looked into this: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html?

Comment: Yes but like i said i dont want to use jquery mobile anymore.

Comment: Ok, maybe something like this then: http://www.tinywall.info/2012/02/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu.html

Comment: I just built a single page application using phonegap and angularJS. There are many good articles stating that jquerymobile is too "heavy" for mobile apps. AngularJs is way more powerfull, offers a lot of resources, including animating.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start working with Ionic Framework:

http://ionicframework.com/

It's works with AngularJS, and has the functionality you are looking for. It also works great with jQuery.

I've build a couple of apps with it myself and I'm still really fond of it!

There are other frameworks like:

- OnsenUI (http://onsenui.io/)
- Kendo UI (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui)
- Sencha (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)
- Monaca(http://monaca.mobi/en/)
- ReactJS (http://facebook.github.io/react/)

Hope it helps!